# javascript bind method this

Tags: javascript, function, methods, bind

Could someone please explain to me to which object is the **this** word referring to in below code?

```
var fullAgeJapan=arrayCalc(ages,isFullAge.bind(this,20));
```

If I replace this with `ages(isFullAge.bind(ages,20))`, it behaves the same way, and I tried console logging the **this** object in the `isFullAge` function but it returns a bunch of information I don't quite understand.

```
var years=[1990,1965,1937,2005,1998];

function arrayCalc(arr,fn){
  var arrRes=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return arrRes;
}
function calculateAge(el){
   return 2020-el;
}

function isFullAge(limit,el){

   return el>=limit;

}
var ages=arrayCalc(years,calculateAge);
var fullAgeJapan=arrayCalc(ages,isFullAge.bind(this,20));
console.log(years);
console.log(ages);
console.log(fullAgeJapan);
```

Comment: In sloppy (default) mode in a browser, `this` is the `window` object. In strict mode it would be `undefined`. You can verify by checking `this === window`.

Comment: `this` is contextual and will have a value based on a number of factors. I suggest you [study it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

At top level `this` is the `window` object. (because you are not in `"strict mode"`)

```js
var years=[1990,1965,1937,2005,1998];

function arrayCalc(arr,fn){
  var arrRes=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return arrRes;
}
function calculateAge(el){
   return 2020-el;
}

function isFullAge(limit,el){

   return el>=limit;

}
var ages=arrayCalc(years,calculateAge);
console.log(this===window)
var fullAgeJapan=arrayCalc(ages,isFullAge.bind(this,20));
console.log(years);
console.log(ages);
console.log(fullAgeJapan);
```

Answer (score 0):

In sloppy (default) mode in a browser, `this` is the `window` object. In strict mode it would be `undefined`. You can verify yourself by asserting that `this === window`.

However, since your function `isFullAge` does not itself refer to `this`, it does not really matter what you pass as first argument to `bind`. In such cases it would be more clean to just pass `null` instead.